# Remove the value of multidimension element from array if it is duplicated?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimension array look like this

```
$input = Array
                      (
                          [222] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 222
                                  'val' => 'def'
                                  'more' => 'test'
                              ),
                        [223] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 223
                                  'val' => 'aaa'
                                  'more' => 'aaa'
                              ),
                        [224] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 224
                                  'val' => 'aaa'
                                  'more' => 'ddd'
                              )
                        [225] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 225
                                  'val' => 'def'
                                  'more' => 'test'
                              )
            );
```

*Duplicate Because  its values of keys `val` and `more` duplicated

I want to remove the duplicate value (in this case the $input[222] and $input[225].so the result should only

```
$res = Array
                      (
                          [222] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 222
                                  'val' => 'def'
                                  'more' => 'test'
                              ),
                        [223] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 223
                                  'val' => 'aaa'
                                  'more' => 'aaa'
                              ),
                        [224] => Array
                              (
                                  'id' => 224 
                                   'val' => 'aaa'
                                  'more' => 'ddd'
                              )
            );
```

Anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Comment: You'd have to do this programmatically (loop through the array, keep a list of ids encountered, and check each entry against that list). However, if you're getting this data from a database, you could probably modify the query to remove duplicates.

Comment: Try using a `GROUP` and `ORDER` to get the result you want. Something like this: `SELECT id, val, more FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY [timestamp or other order determining field]`

Comment: I could not modified the query ,because this result only use for my case.and other will allowed to display result that have duplicated result.So my approach is do with array.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newInput = array();
 foreach($input as $k => $v) $newInput[$v['val'].$v['more']] = $v;
 //You may stop here. 
 $newInputNum = array();
 foreach($newInput as $k => $v) $newInputNum[$v['id']] = $v;

 echo "<pre>";print_r($newInputNum  );echo "</pre>";
```